# SQLConnection Leakage Issue (Timeout Expired due to Pooling - ASP.NET / SQL Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am developing a web application which is based on ASP.NET 4.0, jQuery, AJAX, Javascript using SQL Server 2008 database. Our application is an ERP application which has almost around 400 to 500 users using the application. We have made it live since a month ago.

Now, I'm facing a *timeout issue* and **application crashed literally** which is occurred after **some hours** of **application usage**.

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the     pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max     pool size was reached. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web     request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and     where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout     period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred     because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Source Error: 

Line 36:         param[1].Value = Password;
Line 37: 
Line 38:         return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CDSGlobal.ConnectionString,     CommandType.StoredProcedure, "ValidateLogin_sp", param);
Line 39:     }
Line 40: 


Source File: e:\abcd\App_Code\User.cs    Line: 38 

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to     obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled     connections were in use and max pool size was reached.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection     owningConnection) +6352273
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection     outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6352606
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +300
   DBConn.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(String connectionString, CommandType commandType,     String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters) +270
   User.ValidateLogin(String Employee_Code, String Password) in e:\abcd\App_Code    \User.cs:38
   User_UserLogin.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\abcd    \User\UserLogin.ascx.cs:79
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,     Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET     Version:4.0.30319.272
```

For temporary resolution, we are restarting the server and restarting the `MSSQLSERVER` service.

After searching for above, I came to know it is due to **connection leakage**. Some opened connections are never get closed.

I am using ready made **Microsoft Data Access Application Block for .NET i.e. SQLHelper Class** which in my application for data access using Dataset and all.

Note: I am NOT using `SqlDataReader` anywhere.

I have examined the class and its closing the connections and I have NEVER used manual connection code instead used SQLHelper everywhere.

I also have the following nested transactions structure in stored procedures as follows:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Every below stored procedure has the transation structure as this SP i.e. Parent SP. (BEGIN TRY, BEGIN TRANSACTION etc)

exec sp1

exec sp2

exec sp3

---
---


COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  PRINT 'ERROR OCCURED In SP'
END CATCH
```

Now, The problem is *why connection leakage is occurring*.

1. Is above transaction structure is responsible i.e it is blocking the transactions and requests.
2. If request is in process and user has *closed the browser*, does the *application closes the connection*?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The server does not know anything about "user closes browser"...

Comment: Thanx @Yahia but does Application_End event got called when user closes the browser that means application is closed right ?

Comment: not always... the session might just timeout...

Comment: Please Help .. I am really stuck !!

Comment: Please somebody help.. Is there any issue in my asked question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !!

It was not due to Nested Transactions but it was due to **Bad Indexes Strategy** used. Used normal Indexes and **Indexes with include** to solve the performance issues.

Also ran **SQL Profiler** to examine the **most read and writes** on columns and accordingly applied indexes and review **maintenance** and **execution plans**. !!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this,

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

The above code then closes all of the pools upon execution. I had the same problem and cleared the pools each time and then it should work successfully due to the pools being cleared.